# Why does Google Data Studio only show unique values?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a custom connector which fetches data, and in some cases it contains duplicated rows, for example:

```
[ 
  {name: "test", amount: 120},
  {name: "test2", amount: 150},
  {name: "test", amount: 120}
]
```

Data Studio shows only two on them - `test` and `test2`, but I don't use any aggregation or additional functions to transform data, and I didn't find how to disable it and show result set as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Data Studio [Aggregates](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174) data by Dimension, thus one approach would be to include a dimension field with unique values, for example an `ID` field where each value is unique.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3594fd73-fe32-40a0-8fbb-0866d8a37946) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]